# Golang how to avoid double quoted on key "on" when marshaling struct to yaml

Tags: go, yaml

I have a simple struct such as:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    On string `yaml:"on"`
}
```

And want to marshal this struct into YAML string in either way

- way 1: https://go.dev/play/p/Btwt3Gi09ZG
- way 2: https://go.dev/play/p/r9jwscnuOAR

Always get the same result **with double-quote on key "on"**

```yaml
"on": hello
```

How can I avoid this? Following is the result I want

```yaml
on: hello
```

The version of go is `go1.17.2 darwin/amd64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be invalid YAML1.1 (or at least confusing) because `on` is keyword interpreted as boolean value `true` (see [YAML1.1 spec](https://yaml.org/type/bool.html)).

As per `go-yaml` [documentation](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/tree/v3#compatibility):

> The yaml package supports most of YAML 1.2, but preserves some behavior from 1.1 for backwards compatibility.

> Specifically, as of v3 of the yaml package:
>
> - YAML 1.1 bools (yes/no, on/off) are supported as long as they are being decoded into a typed bool value. Otherwise they behave as a string. Booleans in YAML 1.2 are true/false only.

If you change `yaml:"on"` to anything else like `yaml:"foo"` key will not be quoted.

```golang
type T struct {
    On  string `yaml:"on"`
    Foo string `yaml:"foo"`
}

func main() {
    t := T{
        On:  "Hello",
        Foo: "world",
    }

    b, _ := yaml.Marshal(&t)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

// "on": hello
// foo: world
```